# Hibernate @ManyToMany relationship with composite keys that share a property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I am working with a database that uses a lot of composite keys.  I am trying to use JPA/hibernate to set up an JoinTable for one of the relationships.  Here is a trimmed down example of what is being done

### Parent Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROTAGONIST")
public class Protagonist {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id;}

    @Column(name = "pro_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}
}
```

### Item ID Class

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemId {
    private int pId;
    private short invSlot;

    @Column(name = "P_Id", nullable = false)
    public int getpId() {return pId;}

    public void setpId(int pId) { this.pId = pId;}

    @Column(name = "Inv_SlotNum", nullable = false)
    public short getInvSlot() {return invSlot;}

    public void setInvSlot(short invSlot) { this.invSlot = invSlot;}
}
```

### Item Class

```
public class Item {
    private ItemId id;
    private String itemName;
    private Double cost;
    private Set<Buff> buffs;

    @EmbeddedId
    public ItemId getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(ItemId id) { this.id = id;}

    @Column(name = "Item_Name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getItemName() {return itemName;}

    public void setItemName(String name) { this.itemName = name;}

    @Column(name = "Item_Cost")
    public Double getCost() {return cost;}

    public void setCost(Double cost) { this.cost = cost;}

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "BUFFSONITEMS",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "P_Id", referencedColumnName = "P_Id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "Inv_SlotNum", referencedColumnName = "Inv_SlotNum")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "P_Id", referencedColumnName = "P_Id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "Buff_SlotNum", referencedColumnName = "Buff_SlotNum")
        }
    )
    public Set<Buff> getBuffs() {return buffs;}

    public void setBuffs(Set<Buff> buffs) { this.buffs = buffs;}
}
```

### Buff ID Class

```
@Embeddable
public class BuffId {
    private Integer pId;
    private Short buffSlotNum;

    @Column(name = "P_Id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getpId() {return pId;}

    public void setpId(Integer pId) { this.pId = pId;}

    @Column(name = "Buff_SlotNum", nullable = false)
    public Short getBuffSlotNum() {return buffSlotNum;}

    public void setBuffSlotNum(Short buffSeqNum) { this.buffSlotNum = buffSeqNum;}
}
```

### Buff Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUFF")
public class Buff {
    private BuffId id;
    private String buffName;
    private Long duration;
    private Set<Item> buffedItems;

    @EmbeddedId
    public BuffId getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(BuffId id) { this.id = id;}

    @Column(name = "Buff_Name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getBuffName() {return buffName;}

    public void setBuffName(String name) { this.buffName = name;}

    @Column(name = "Duration", nullable = false)
    public Long getDuration() {return duration;}

    public void setDuration(Long duration) { this.duration = duration;}

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "BUFFSONITEMS",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "P_Id", referencedColumnName = "P_Id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "Buff_SlotNum", referencedColumnName = "Buff_SlotNum")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "P_Id", referencedColumnName = "P_Id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "Inv_SlotNum", referencedColumnName = "Inv_SlotNum")
        }
    )
    public Set<Item> getBuffedItems() {return buffedItems;}

    public void setBuffedItems(Set<Item> buffedItems) { this.buffedItems = buffedItems;}
}
```

Whenever I attempt to start Spring Boot I get the following exception **org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.blankd.composite.key.Item.buffs column: P_Id**.  The BUFFSONITEMS table uses all 3 columns as part of the primary key for each row in that table.  All three columns also have forgein key constraints on the respective tables.  This means that P_Id has a forgein key constraint on both Buff and Item.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I need the P_Id in order to uniquely identify the row in each table.

Answer (score 2):

You have to choose one side of the many-to-many relationship to be the "owning" side. The "inverse" side must then use the `mappedBy` element.

If you were to choose `Item.buffs` to be the owning side, you would map `Buff.buffedItems` like this:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="buffs")
    public Set<Item> getBuffedItems() {return buffedItems;}
```

Comment: even when I use the mappedBy parameter I still get the same error.  The example I gave was extremely simplified.  There another object which uses a ManyToOne relationship and JoinColumns that also maps P_Id as one of the columns to use.  Could this be causing problems?

Comment: @dblanken You might need to use a "derived identity". This is described in the [JPA spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) section 2.4.1.

Comment: I am not seeing anything relating to many-to-many relationships in that column.  I am trying to avoid using a one-to-many relationship on my join table.